# I want a Imageview inside SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, android-imageview, simpleadapter

Could someone point me in the right direction to get a ImageView inside this SimpleAdapter?
The TAG_IMAGE should be the Imageview.
I am getting this: Type missmatch: Cannot convert from ImageView to int.
And yes I am a noob.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_RANDOM, TAG_IMAGE },                               
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price,
                                R.id.random, R.id.image });
                // Imageview to show
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 15):

Main.xml with the given below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

listview_layout.xml  and update the content with the given below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java with the given below code

```
package com.example.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistan",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.india,
        R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.srilanka,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.nepal,
        R.drawable.afghanistan,
        R.drawable.nkorea,
        R.drawable.skorea,
        R.drawable.japan
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Run the application

Comment: I don't understand how the adapter knows that it should set the flag as the src of the ImageView, and that it should set the text for the TextViews. Is it because it looks at the type of the target View and makes an assumption e.g. if it's an ImageView, then the relevant mapped value must be a drawable that it'll use as the src?

Comment: @Code That doesn't explain how the adapter knows that R.id.flag references an ImageView and R.id.txt references a TextView. It appears the SimpleAdapter doing some sort of introspection on the element referenced and then it magically knows which property to set (text or src) depending on the element type. Is that correct?

Comment: Looking at the source code for SimpleAdapter, it works the way I described above. It checks the type of the referenced element and the type of the mapped value and then makes a best guess at what property you wanted to set. Looks like it can support TextView, ImageView, and Checkable (Checkbox, RadioButton, Switch, etc.) elements.