# How can I get the Image ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I want to convert the `(R.drawable.logo)object` to a `string` and I want to show it in the `listview`. I used the following code for it but it did not work

```
 Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
 ByteArrayOutputStream ByteStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, ByteStream);
 byte [] b = ByteStream.toByteArray();
 String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
     Welcome.this,
     contactList,
     R.layout.about,
     new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SURNAME, temp },
     new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.surname, R.id.imageView}
 );

 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> ERROR:
>       Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: are you getting string value for the image.

Comment: You mean that you want to convert a bitmap to Base64 string?

Comment: @BoldijarPaul Yes I try it but not work

Comment: @ManojFrekzz Yes I getting

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? Is easier just to send the ID of the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the image in `ListView` using `SimpleAdapter` you don't need to convert your image to a Base64 string.

Change `new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SURNAME, temp }` to `new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SURNAME, TAG_IMAGE }`.

Inside your `contactList` array add the image as follows,

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put(TAG_NAME, names[i]);
    hm.put(TAG_SURNAME, surnames[i]);
    hm.put(TAG_IMAGE, Integer.toString(R.drawable.logo) );
    contactList.add(hm);
}
```

This will set the `R.drawable.logo` for all rows.

But the error you are getting is a `FileNotFoundException`. So also cross check if the image exists too.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064855/i-want-a-imageview-inside-simpleadapter) SO thread.

Comment: tank u so much @K Neeraj Lal